# how to run jsf with primefaces in glassfish server

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, glassfish

I am facing one problem in running jsf with primefaces application in glassfish server. It is not deploying i am getting an error like this

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.crimson.tree.ElementNode2.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String;. Please see server.log for more details.
```

can anyone help me to fix this issue
I am using xhtml pages for primefaces 3.5 tags using jpa, it is running in apache server successfully but not in glassfish server.

i've removed eclipselink jpa used for database connection then also im getting this error.

Comment: please attach server.log for more detail.

Comment: My server --> logException Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.crimson.tree.ElementNode2.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String;. Please see server.log for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the follwing:

1. Delete all occurences of Primefaces and restart the server. Test if
   JSF is working properly.
2. Insert Primefaces.jar in WEB-INF/lib and redeploy. Are there errors?
3. Do a simple Primefaces test like `<p:spinner />`. Is this working?